# Assign processors to Hyper V host machine optimally

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

We have a Intel Core i7-3632QM CPU (4 Cores, 8 Threads, 8 Symbols in device manager) on a host machine with Windows 8.
We have a single Hyper V virtual machine with Windows Server 2012.

How do we optimally allocate physical cores/threads for the virtual machine, meaning what should be put into field

> Number of virtual processors

And WHY?

I didn't get a thing about vCPU, HT and recommendations from Microsoft, so please don't feed that eyewashed links.. Plain Tech-English would be great!

I want to Dynamically utilize 100% of Host CPU (or perhaps 95% if that's the case/possible), can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Options of a virtual Machine in Hyper V show in percent how many host resources will be allocated/dedicated to a Guest machine.
So if you have 8 Threads (8 virtual CPUs) on your host, then 8 virtual CPUs in VM's settings means, that Guest will be able to use all 8 Host threads.